# How do I fix ‘Eq a’ has kind ‘GHC.Prim.Constraint’ error in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

I am writing a small function in Haskell to check if a list is a palindrome by comparing it with it's reverse.

```
checkPalindrome :: [Eq a] -> Bool
checkPalindrome l = (l == reverse l)
                    where
                        reverse :: [a] -> [a]
                        reverse xs
                            | null xs = []
                            | otherwise = (last xs) : reverse newxs
                                  where
                                      before = (length xs) - 1
                                      newxs = take before xs
```

I understand that I should use [Eq a] in the function definition because I use the equality operator later on, but I get this error when I compile:

```
Expected kind ‘*’, but ‘Eq a’ has kind ‘GHC.Prim.Constraint’
In the type signature for ‘checkPalindrome’:
  checkPalindrome :: [Eq a] -> Bool
```

P.s Feel free to correct me if I am doing something wrong with my indentation, I'm very new to the language.

Comment: If you type your function definition (*without* the type) into GHCi (use `:{` to enter multiline mode; paste it in; use `:}` to exit), then you can say `:type checkPalindrome` (or just `:t`) to see what GHC thinks your type should be. You can also put `_`s in types, like `checkPalindrome :: _ => [a] -> Bool`, and if `-XPartialTypeSignatures` is *off* (it is by default), you'll get an error where GHC tells you how it filled in the blank.

Answer (score 6):

Unless Haskell adopted a new syntax, your type signature should be:

```
checkPalindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

Declare the constraint on the left hand side of a fat-arrow, then use it on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike OO languages, Haskell makes a quite fundamental distinction between

- **Constraints** – typeclasses like `Eq`.
- **Types** – concrete types like `Bool` or lists of some type.

In OO languages, both of these would be represented by [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Class_(object-oriented_programming))<sup>†</sup>, but a [Haskell type class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) is completely different. You never have “values of class `C`”, only “*types* of class `C`”. (These concrete types may then contain values, but the classes don't.)

This distinction may seem pedantic, but it's actually very useful. What you wrote, `[Eq a] -> Bool`, would supposedly mean: each element of the list must be comparable... but *comparable to what*? You could have elements of different type in the list, how do you know that these elements are comparable *to each other*? In Haskell, that's no issue, because whenever the function is used you first settle on one type `a`. This type must be in the `Eq` class. The list then must have all elements from the same type `a`. This way you ensure that each element of the list is comparable to all of the others, not just, like, *comparable to itself*. Hence the signature

```
checkPalindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

This is the usual distinction on the syntax level: **constraints must always<sup>‡</sup> be written on the left of an `=>` (implication arrow)**.

The constraints before the `=>` are “implicit arguments”: you don't explicitly “pass `Eq a` to the function” when you call it, instead you just pass the stuff after the `=>`, i.e. in your example a list of some concrete type. The compiler will then look at the type and automatically look up its `Eq` typeclass instance (or raise a compile-time error if the type does *not* have such an instance). Hence,

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let palin :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool; palin l = l==reverse l
Prelude> palin [1,2,3,2,1]
True
Prelude> palin [1,2,3,4,5]
False
Prelude> palin [sin, cos, tan]

<interactive>:5:1:
    No instance for (Eq (a0 -> a0))
      (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
      arising from a use of ‘palin’
    In the expression: palin [sin, cos, tan]
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = palin [sin, cos, tan]
```

...because functions can't be equality-compared.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Constraints may in OO also be *interfaces* / abstract base classes, which aren't “quite proper classes” but are still in many ways treated the same way as OO value-classes. Most modern OO languages now also support Haskell-style parametric polymorphism in addition to “element-wise”/covariant/existential polymorphism, but they require somewhat awkward `extends` trait-mechanisms because this was only implemented as an afterthought.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>There are also functions which have “constraints in the arguments”, but that's a more advanced concept called [rank-*n* polymorphism](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#arbitrary-rank-polymorphism).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is really an extended comment. Aside from your little type error, your function has another problem: it's extremely inefficient. The main problem is your definition of `reverse`.

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse xs
  | null xs = []
  | otherwise = (last xs) : reverse newxs
      where
        before = (length xs) - 1
        newxs = take before xs
```

`last` is O(n), where n is the length of the list. `length` is also O(n), where n is the length of the list. And `take` is O(k), where k is the length of the result. So your `reverse` will end up taking O(n^2) time. One fix is to just use the standard `reverse` function instead of writing your own. Another is to build up the result recursively, accumulating the result as you go:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse xs0 = go [] xs0
  go acc [] = acc
  go acc (x : xs) = go (x : acc) xs
```

This version is O(n).

There's another source of inefficiency in your implementation:

```
checkPalindrome l = (l == reverse l)
```

This isn't nearly as bad, but let's look at what it does. Suppose we have the string `"abcdefedcba"`. Then we test whether `"abcdefedcba" == "abcdefedcba"`. By the time we've checked half the list, we already know the answer. So we'd like to stop there! There are several ways to accomplish this. The simplest efficient one is probably to calculate the length of the list as part of the process of reversing it so we know how much we'll need to check:

```
reverseCount :: [a] -> (Int, [a])
reverseCount xs0 = go 0 [] xs0 where
  go len acc [] = (len, acc)
  go len acc (x : xs) = len `seq`
                        go (len + 1) (x : acc) xs
```

Don't worry about the `` len `seq` `` bit too much; that's just a bit of defensive programming to make sure laziness doesn't make things inefficient; it's probably not even necessary if optimizations are enabled. Now you can write a version of `==` that only looks at the first `n` elements of the lists:

```
eqTo :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [a] -> Bool
eqTo 0 _ _ = True
eqTo _ [] [] = True
eqTo n (x : xs) (y : ys) =
  x == y && eqTo (n - 1) xs ys
eqTo _ _ _ = False
```

So now

```
isPalindrome xs = eqTo ((len + 1) `quot` 2) xs rev_xs
  where
    (len, rev_xs) = reverseCount xs
```

---

Here's another way, that's more efficient and arguably more elegant, but a bit tricky. We don't actually need to reverse the whole list; we only need to reverse half of it. This saves memory allocation. We can use a tortoise and hare trick:

```
splitReverse ::
  [a] ->
  ( [a] -- the first half, reversed
  , Maybe a -- the middle element
  , [a] ) -- the second half, in order
splitReverse xs0 = go [] xs0 xs0 where
  go front rear [] = (front, Nothing, rear)
  go front (r : rs) [_] = (front, Just r, rs)
  go front (r : rs) (_ : _ : xs) =
    go (r : front) rs xs
```

Now

```
isPalindrome xs = front == rear
  where
    (front, _, rear) = splitReverse xs
```

---

Now for some numbers, using the test case

```
somePalindrome :: [Int]
somePalindrome = [1..10000] ++ [10000,9999..1]
```

Your original implementation takes 7.523s (2.316 mutator; 5.204 GC) and allocates 11 *gigabytes* to build the test list and check if it's a palindrome. My counting implementation takes less than 0.01s and allocates 2.3 *megabytes*. My tortoise and hare implementation takes less than 0.01s and allocates 1.7 megabytes.